# Show that P(A|B) > P(A) if and only if $P(B|A^c) < P(B|A)$.

Tags: probability

I currently have that $\mathsf P(B\mid A^c) < \mathsf P(B\mid A)$ leads to: $$\mathsf P(A^c\mid B)\,\mathsf P(B)\big/\mathsf P(A^c) < \mathsf P(A\mid B)\,\mathsf P(B)\big/\mathsf P(A)$$ ... due to Bayes.

This then gives us: $$\mathsf P(A^c\mid B)\,\mathsf P(A) < \mathsf P(A\mid B)\,\mathsf P(A^c)$$

But since we assume $\mathsf P(A\mid B) > \mathsf P(A)$, we then get $$\mathsf P(A^c\mid B)\,\mathsf P(A) < \mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(A^c)$$... which gives us : $$\mathsf P(A^c\mid B) < \mathsf P(A^c)$$..., which doesn't entirely make sense.

If I try to tackle it from the other way and assume $P(B\mid A^c) < P(B\mid A)$, then I start with $$\mathsf P(A\mid B) > \mathsf P(A)$$ leads to $$\mathsf P(B\mid A)\,\mathsf P(A)\big/\mathsf P(B) > \mathsf P(A)$$

This leads to $$\mathsf P(B\mid A)\big/\mathsf P(B) > 1 \implies \mathsf P(B\mid A) > \mathsf P(B)$$  I don't really know where to include $A^c$ from here.

Answer (score 0):

By Bayes Rule
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(A^c)}$$
and this is greater than $P(A)$ if and only if

$$\frac{P(B|A)}{P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(A^c)} > 1$$ or as the denominator is positive,
$$P(B|A) > P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(A^c).$$

As $P(A) + P(A^c) = 1$, this in turn is equivalent to

$$P(B|A)(1-P(A)) > P(B|A^c)(1-P(A)),$$
that is, $$P(B|A) > P(B|A^c).$$

Comment: Is P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|A^c)P(A^c) a definition for the P(B)?  It makes sense.

Comment: @Chris93 $ P(B) = P(B\mid A)P(A) + P(B\mid A^c)P(A^c)$ is an example of a result called the _law of total probability_.